# What will I need to repair the grout in a small section of my bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, tile, waterproofing, grout

I had my bathroom redone last year. Everything is still perfect except for this one tile that popped up just a little bit.Visually it does not bother me at all, but the cracks in the grout worry me and do not look water tight.  There are some hairline cracks away from the main cracked up area where the tile is raised. I would like to repair them, but I have not done work with grout before. Should this be an easy fix if I allow the one off tile to lay as it is? What tools and other items would I need?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Comment: Something is pushing down the floor there to pop the tile. Before the shower stall that is there now, what used to be there?

Comment: There was a toilet where the toilet currently is. There was a shower tub that was converted into the stall that is there now. Is there anything I can do besides redoing the grout and hoping that it is stable now?

Comment: What is below that area? A crawlspace, basement, or finished area?

Comment: the first floor is beneath the bathroom, this is in the master bathroom.

Comment: It's possible that the wax sealing flange on your toilet isn't seating properly and it's leaking a little bit of water under the tile every time you flush it. The added height of the tile floor can make this happen more often. The toilet leaking might be what is causing your tile/grout to fail. Flush the toilet a few times and then remove the toilet to look for water where it shouldn't be. Buy a new extended wax flange before doing this because you should always install a new flange after removing the toilet.

Comment: Who did the original work?  Are they still in business?  They may come back to fix something like this: it's pretty obviously an installation defect.

Comment: I am going to try and find the contract, see if there is any mention of a warranty. Either way I will call the contractor, see if they'll fix it. Otherwise I have a plumber that I really like.

Comment: I found my contract, it said I have a one year warranty. I contacted the company, the owner was happy to setup an inspection of the problem, hopefully they can reseal the toilet and fix the tile and grout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the existing grout with a [grout saw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FSAV10). Your local hardware stores should sell one.

The catch here is re-grouting. You can buy pre-mix grout in pints at some big-box stores, but be prepared for it to not match your existing grout. You may need to saw all the grout out and redo it afresh.

I would remove the toilet first, however. Make sure that tile isn't loose because of the toilet, or improper mounting

Comment: I'd say without knowing what's pushing the tile up, you don't want to just regrout.  Maybe lift the tile and look first, and replace the wax seal.

Comment: The tile will be loose, and there is no way to know if it has stopped moving or not, even with seasonal movement.